# How to tell if a class uses a Trait

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, traits, pharo

If I have a Trait that some classes use but not others, how can I test an object to see if it is an instance of a class that uses that Trait? What I want is something like isMemberOf: or isKindOf: but for Traits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

myInstance class traitCompositionIncludes: MyTraitClass